# How to prevent SQL injection with Qt QSqlQuery?

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I would like to know if there is another way to insert a variable in prepare preventing sql injection

I tried that way but it leaves cause vulnerability i am using QSqlQuery class from qt to perform queries

```
query.prepare("update coins_tb set VALUE='"+QString::fromStdString(match.str(2))+"' where TOKEN='"+QString::fromStdString(match.str(1))+"'");
```

Comment: Which library do you use to perform SQL queries?

Comment: @Dmitry K. i am using a class QSqlQuery from qt

Comment: Did you try reading the manual? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html ("Approaches to Binding Values" section.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example from [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#prepare):

```cpp
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
              "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
query.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");
query.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
query.exec();
```

And with your query it looks like:

```cpp
query.prepare("update coins_tb set VALUE=:value where TOKEN=:token");

query.bindValue(":value", QString::fromStdString(match.str(2)));
query.bindValue(":token", QString::fromStdString(match.str(1)));

query.exec();
```